# Kafka setup on multi node VMs

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I tried looking at multi node setup from https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kafka-docker-setup. I couldnt find how I can set it up on 2 VMs with docker enabled as multi node cluster. Found a similar topic on stackoverflow but it was talking more about pointing one to another.

My question again is, i need redundancy so want to setup kafka on two docker enabled VMs so that they work in tandem as a cluster(ultimately expand to more docker enabled VMs). Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Use Kubernetes, not Docker; that's the main goal of it - to run self recovering, highly available containers. In other words, Docker itself is not an orchestrator ; you'd need Swarm for that

But Swarm doesn't make it easy... Start with an operator such as https://strimzi.io/ which walks you through installation and usage steps

Or, if kubernetes is too much, use Ansible directly on your VMs to configure and run processes without containers https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible